# STRIPE How to redirect after payment (through payment link)

Tags: stripe-payments

Very quick question, I created a stripe payment link with the stripe dashboard to sell a digital product and what I want to do is that when the customer makes the payment it redirects him to an URL (where he will download the product he purchased)

Is it possible to approach directly with the dashboard and no coding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it' possible. You can select the `Don't show confirmation page` option and key in the URL that you want your customer to be redirected to.

[image]